# No DISM is found on my system

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, dism

Windows 7 64-bit. Trying to install IE11 and getting following error:
Launched package installation: C:\Windows\SysNative\dism.exe /online /add-package /packagepath:C:\Windows\TEMP\IE15931.tmp\IE11-neutral.Extracted.cab /quiet /norestart 00:21.684: INFO: Process exit code 0x00000002 (2) [The system cannot find the file specified. ] 00:21.715: ERROR: Neutral package installation failed (exit code = 0x00000002 (2)).

I don't have Windows/**SysNative** folder

Answer (score 0):

Just checked, and I also don't have that folder. Where did you get that installer for IE11? That almost looks like you got a download for some company's custom image.  Specifically, the call to DISM is out of place.  DISM is a utility built into Windows that's used for modifying WIM image files.
The command they're calling there is trying to add the IE11 software to a currently mounted WIM file.  My recommendation would be to go to Microsoft.com and hit up their downloads section. That installer just seems a little odd to me.

Comment: I am trying to install from official package http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie-11-worldwide-languages

Answer (score -1):

There may be cases where a 32-bit program or application might really need a 64-bit DLL. In that case, you will have to use the redirection folder Sysnative. You can consider the SysNative to be an virtual folder and an alias that points to the System32 folder. It doesn’t exist physically on your system, as such. So if your 32-bit program needs to access a 64-bit DLL, do not use C:\Windows\System32 because the 32-bit program emulator will take it to the 32-bit DLL folder called SysWOW64. Instead, use C:\Windows\SysNative as the path to the DLL program. Using Sysnative in the path will redirect it to System32 folder instead of SysWOW64 folder.

What you may try to do is to run the command directly using the direct path (run cmd first in elevated command prompt and then run DISM):

```
C:\Windows\System32\dism.exe /online /add-package /packagepath:C:\Windows\TEMP\IE15931.tmp\IE11-neutral.Extracted.cab /quiet /norestart
```

Take a note that IE11-neutral.Extracted.cab must be already pre-extracted from the installation source and located where you can access it on the disk. It your case installer extracted it to C:\Windows\TEMP\IE15931.tmp by itself.

P.S. Take a note that your need to use correct IE11 installer - they are different for 32 and 64 bit OS:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/Internet-Explorer-11-for-Windows-7-details.aspx